# Сложный sql запрос с условием

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Помогите составить sql запрос.
Есть таблицы:

```
tbl_article(id, title)
tbl_category(id, title)
tbl_tag(id, title, geotag)
```

И таблицы связей:

```
tbl_category_articles(id, category_id, article_id)
tbl_article_tag(id, article_id, tag_id)
```

Нужно выбрать все записи из `tbl_category_articles`, где `category_id = 177`, и если у `article` нет тега у которого поле `geotag = 1`.
В общем-то не знаю как проверку по `geotag` реализовать.

Мой неправильный вариант запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_category_articles` ca
INNER JOIN tbl_article_tagnew at
ON ca.article_id = at.article_id
INNER JOIN tbl_tagnew t
ON at.tag_id = t.id
WHERE ca.category_id = 177
AND t.geotag = 0
```

Comment: Давно не использовал SQL и могу ошибиться с синтаксисом, но по моему, в Вашем запросе надо так "....AND t.geotag <> 1 ...", если конечно я правильно понял структуру Ваши таблиц. Вы бы привели их схему.

Comment: Спасибо, еще не работал с <>. Посмотрю для чего это используется. П.С. указал поля всех таблиц. Все кроме title имеют тип int

Comment: AND t.geotag <> 1 не сработало. Кажется суть в том, что если у статьи будет несколько тегов, хотябы у одного из которых будет поле `geotag = 0`, то эта статья попадает в выборку. А надо чтоб не попадало в выборку если прикреплен хоть один тег с geotag = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, что Вам поможет решить Вашу проблему следующая конструкция:

```
SELECT * from tbl_category_articles WHERE category_id = 177 
AND  article_id NOT IN (
        SELECT tbl_article_tag.article_id 
        FROM tbl_article_tag INNER JOIN tbl_tag 
        ON tbl_article_tag.tag_id = tbl_tag.id 
        WHERE tbl_tag.geotag= 1
        )
```

Сразу должен предупредить, что у меня сейчас нет никаких технических возможностей проверить запрос, поэтому там возможны синтаксические ошибки, но надеюсь, что идея понятна.

P.S. Джентльмены находят, что графическая схема связей таблиц в тексте вопроса ускоряет время получение ответа и уменьшает количество возможных ошибок, особенно если ответ приходится писать "на колене" в обычном текстовом редакторе :).

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо большое Александр! Рекомендацию джентельменов на будущее учту)

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_category_articles` ca
INNER JOIN tbl_article_tagnew at
ON ca.article_id = at.article_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_tagnew t
ON at.tag_id = t.id AND t.geotag = 1
WHERE ca.category_id = 177 and t.geotag is null
```

**Cмысл такой:**

`LEFT JOIN` таблицы, в которой не должно быть этого значения:

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_tag t  ON ... t.geotag = 1
```

Так мы получим выборку где `tbl_tag` приджойнится именно с `geotag = 1` или не приджойнится вообще. И нам нужно только отфильтровать те строки, где не приджойнилось:

```
WHERE ... and t.geotag is null
```

Comment: похоже что-то пошло не так и в выборку попала запись со статьей у которой есть тег с `geotag = 1`

Comment: Запрос мой взяли, покажите?

Comment: Да. Подозреваю что не пошло из за того, что у этой статьи есть также тег с geotag = 0, из за чего ее не исключает

Comment: Я бы посмотрел выборку. в теории должно сработать

Comment: Возможно, `left join` нужен на таблицу `tbl_article_tagnew` я, возможно, не понял схему вашей базы.

Comment: Из выборки не понятно, что у одной из статей есть нежеланный тег т.к. во всех значениях колонки geoteg стоит NULL

Comment: `left join` для `tbl_article_tagnew` тоже не сработал

Comment: для чего вообще tbl_article_tagnew?

Comment: для связи таблиц `tbl_article` с `tbl_tag` (один ко многим). Структура таблицы: `id|article_id|tag_id`

Comment: Есть предположение что тут надо оператор `EXISTS` использовать